# Nokia Lumia 920 - cannot find recorded video after low space

Tags: video

Was recording a video and windows prompted a low space alert. This has happened in the past and windows still was able to create a video file that I could see in both the camera roll and from desktop. However this time there is no file and the storage space shows that the file must be on the phone as I had 2GB available before recording and only 1MB left now.  I have powered on/off and soft reset the phone. But still no video file and still have only 1MB. How can I clear this file if windows doesn't even show it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer but this exact thing happened to me today....dis you ever find out how to fix??? Please share if you did....i have deleted all my apps and clearing through my photos with the hope that if I make more space it will be revealed.